# target an element check for content legnth and remove class from span

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue targeting a specific element and removing a class. Within the HTML below, I am looking at the ul > li > ul, checking to see if it has a value, and then needing to remove the class from a tag from the first lu within the span. Using the example below, checking the first ul > li > ul, it is empty, so I would remove the class of js from the a tag of "Home". My issue is that this has to be dynamic, I cant just specify "Home", or "About me".

```
<ul class="Nav">
    <li>
         <span class="scChromeData"></span>
         <span id="fld_A0F4D47685ED4" class="WebInput">
             <a class="children js" href="/">Home</a>
         </span>
         <ul class="NavChild hide js" style="display: none;"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
        <span class="scChromeData"></span>
        <span id="Span1" class="WebInput">
            <a class="children js" href="/">About me</a>
        </span>
        <ul class="NavChild hide js" style="display: none;"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery I was writing:

```
if ( $('li > ul').children().length > 0 ) {
     $( "li > span > a.js" ).removeClass( "js" )
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("li > ul").each(function(){
   if($(this).children().length > 0){
        $(this).parent().find("span a.js").removeClass("myClass yourClass")
   }

})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7F43P/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this should do it for you.

```
$("ul li ul").each(function()
{
    if($(this).html() == "")
    {
        $(this).prev().children("a").removeClass("js");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/qZyKY/)

```
$("ul.Nav > li > ul").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    if (!$.trim($this.html()))  // Check if it's empty ignoring whitespaces
    {
        $this                   // The UL
            .closest('li')      // Find it's closest parent LI
            .find('.js')        // Find all instances of class 'js' within the LI
            .removeClass('js'); // Remove it
    }
});
```